# Regular Expression: Match lines not starting with 32 spaces in Notedpad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

In **Notepad++**, I'm trying to match lines *not* starting with 32 consecutive spaces.

I already have the regex that matches lines starting with 32 consecutive spaces: `^ {32}.*$`

I tried with `^[^ {32}].*$` and `^[^( {32})].*$` with the same wrong result, doesn't match lines with only 24 spaces for example.

Comment: What about a line starting with *more* that 32 spaces?

Comment: @Kobi I have edited the question and replaced the word *exactly* with *consecutive* so that it's more clear what I mean.

Comment: @cprcrack: can you add if you are looking for *exactly* 32 spaces as well, that is, 33 spaces should also be matched? (I addressed this in my answer but don't know which of my two suggestions you picked.)

Comment: @Jongware A line with 33 spaces should not be matched because that means it also starts with 32 spaces, and I'm looking for lines *not* starting with 32 spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything inside your straight brackets form a single character class, so

```
[^ {32}]
```

matches (not) any of the individual characters , `{`, `3`, `2`, and `}`. The "(not)" is because the first character is a negation. (It does not help.)

What you are looking for is a Negative Lookahead:

```
^(?! {32}).+$
```

This tests each line and selects it if it is not followed by *at least* 32 spaces. To match not only exactly 32 spaces and not more, use another lookahead inside the first one:

```
^(?! {32}(?! )).+$
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Match less than 32 spaces, followed by non-space: http://www.regexr.com/3au2l

   ```
   ^ {0,31}[^ ]
   ```
2. Match "not 32 spaces" using a negative lookahead: http://regexr.com/3au2o

   ```
    ^(?! {32})
   ```

In both cases, add `.*` to match the whole line, if required.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a negative lookahead.

```
(?!^ {32}[^ ]*$)^ +.*$
```

What the first part(in parentheses) does: It matches a line starting with exactly 32 spaces, and excludes it.

Finally, the second part matches all lines starting with any number of spaces.